# Open each div after clicking a button in a list of buttons

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

How to implement an action to open a each `div` which is associated with each `button`?

I have a `html`

```
  <ol *ngFor="let g of guides">
    <button type="button" class="form-control" (click)="open(g)">{{g.description}}</button>
    <div [hidden]="!canOpen" style="text-align: center">test</div>
  </ol>
</div>
```

In which variable `canOpen` is a for whole `component`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you :

**Template Side :**

```
<button (click)="openAll()">Toggle Div</button>

<ol *ngFor="let g of guides">
    <button type="button" class="form-control" (click)="open(g)">{{g.description}}</button>
    <div [hidden]="!canOpen || openAllDiv" style="text-align: center">test</div>
</ol>
```

**Component Side :**

```
openAllDiv = false;
openAll() {
    this.openAllDiv = !this.openAllDiv;
}
```

Comment: Where do you open each div?

Comment: onclick of "Toggle Div" it will

Comment: As I know it will open every div

Comment: Yes It wil, as you have not post the code for it, this is the same way you can do it

Comment: I did something like this: `open(guide) {
    if(!guide.canOpen){
      guide.canOpen = true;
    } else {
      guide.canOpen = false;
    }
  }` but I don't think so it is a good solution..what do you think?

Comment: there is nothing wrong in it , but you can shoten your code by this , open(guide) { 
 guide.canOpen = !guide.canOpen;
}